# How do you extract the date of an event item in the Google Calendar API?

Tags: java, date, datetime, google-calendar-api

Does anyone here know/understand Google's Calendar API?
I'm stuck trying to understand how to get the date for an event in a calendar. I've tried using DateTime, EventDateTime, and Date, and I'm not sure what to do. Here's the code so far:

```
public static void main(String... args) throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
    // Build a new authorized API client service.
    final NetHttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
    Calendar service =
            new Calendar.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, getCredentials(HTTP_TRANSPORT))
                    .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME)
                    .build();

    // This is meant to iterate over a list of event items in a calendar and I want to get the event name (get.Summary) and the event date because I want to duplicate the event from a public calender to a private (primary) calendar. Any help is appreciated :)
    String pageToken = null;
    do {
        Events events = service.events().list("imagine there's a calendarID over here").setPageToken(pageToken).execute();
        List<Event> items = events.getItems();

        for (Event event : items) {
            String item = event.getSummary();
            Date date = new Date(event.getDate());
        }
        pageToken = events.getNextPageToken();
    } while (pageToken != null);
```

So far, when I use DateTime to create a new variable, i.e. DateTime date = event.getStart().getDate(), it shows (in the debugger) that the date value is null. I don't understand why this is. It does the same thing when I use EventDateTime too.